# Rails form posting to /new instead of /create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple form view using a Rails 3.1.x application:

```
<%= form_for(:mymodel) do |f| %>
  <% if @mymodel.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@mymodel.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this model from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @mymodel.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    Amount:
    <%= f.text_field :count %><br /><br />
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When submit is hit here, it posts to `/mymodels/new`. How do I force it to go to the right create action for mymodels_controller.rb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1:** Follow the conventions and supply a new, unsaved record to the `form_for` helper. You probably already have such object on `@mymodel`, set on your `new` action of your controller. So the following snippet should work nicely:

```
<%= form_for(@mymodel) do |f| %>
```

If it does not work, you can set `@mymodel` on your action like this:

```
class MyModelsController
  def new
    @mymodel = MyModel.new
  end
end
```

**Option 2:** Be explicit about your URL and method:

```
<%= form_for(:mymodel, :url => create_mymodel_path, :method => :post) do |f| %>
```

Comment: I was able to fix this with the `@mymodel` but it may be worth noting that `@mymodel` should be set in the controller. So it will look something like `def new
    @mymodel = MyModel.new()
  end` in the controller then `<%= form_for @mymodel do |f|` in the view. This will now submit to `/create` of that controller.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the correct way of fixing this problem. Everyone else on the internet seems to think using `match` or similar in `routes.rb` is the solution. I searched for a real solution and you have given it. You may want to expand you answer to include the info of my previous comment because `You probably already have an initialized empty object on @mymodel` doesn't show them how to if they don't already and my comment may be overlooked and isn't formatted with line breaks.