# Rails 3.2.8 form_for submit button is using the 'new' action instead of 'create' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

After filling in my form with values. Clicking on f.submit just refreshes my view (new.html.erb). I am attempting to save the form to my db and redirect to my index view.

I have tried the following:

1. Removed conditional statement from posts_controller create action.
2. Changed my nested resources into a singular resource (of posts).
3. Passed routing options via the url hash in my form.

I have also followed the pertinent advice in these SO questions with no success.

1. [Rails Create Action Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429097/rails-create-action-not-working?rq=1)https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
2. [rails form_for never invokes the create controller action to use redirect_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956346/rails-form-for-never-invokes-the-create-controller-action-to-use-redirect-to)
3. [Rails form posting to /new instead of /create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180862/rails-form-posting-to-new-instead-of-create)

Here is my code:

```
-- views/posts/index.html.erb
<h5>Posts#index</h5>
<small><i>Find me in app/views/posts/index.html.erb</i></small>
<hr />

<div class="hero hero-unit">
    <button><%= link_to "Create a post", new_post_path %></button>
    <hr />

    <ul class="unstyled">
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>

        <h5><small>post ID: </small><%= post.id %></h5>
        <li><%= post.URL %></li>
        <li>
            <%= link_to post.description, post %>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="unstyled">
                <li><small><i>submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago.</i></small></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <%= pluralize(post.comments.count, 'comment') %>
        </li>
        <!-- votes moved to votes/index.html.erb -->
        <li>
            <button class="btn btn-mini btn-success">
                <%= link_to '', post_votes_path(post, vote: "true"), method: :post, remote: true, class: 'icon-arrow-up' %>
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger">
                <%= link_to '', post_votes_path(post, vote: "false"), method: :post, remote: true, class: 'icon-arrow-down' %>
            </button>
            <p><%= post.vote_total.to_s + " votes" %></p>
            <!-- 
                <span id="post_<%= post.id %>_votes"><%= post.vote_total.to_s + " votes" %></span>
            -->
        </li>
        <% end %>
        <hr />
    </ul>
</div><!-- END hero, hero-unit CLASS -->



-- views/posts/new.html.erb

    <h5>Posts#new</h5>
<small><i>Find me in app/views/posts/new.html.erb</i></small>
<hr />

<div class="hero hero-unit">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">
                <%= f.label "Select post type" %> 
            </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <%= f.select :is_link, options_for_select([["Link", true], ["Text", false]]) %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="URL"><%= f.label :URL %></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <%= f.text_field :URL %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="description"><%= f.label :description %></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 5 %>
            </div><br />
            <div class="controls">
                <%= f.submit 'save post' %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form> 
</div><!-- end hero, hero-unit CLASS -->



-- posts_controller.rb

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.find(:all)
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def show
    # Post 
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    # Comments assiciated by :post_id 
    @comments = @post.comments.all
    @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.save
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end




-- config/routes.rb

  root to: 'posts#index'

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
    resources :votes
  end
.
.
.
#match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'

--Terminal rake routes

             root        /                                           posts#index
    post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                  POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                  PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
       post_votes GET    /posts/:post_id/votes(.:format)             votes#index
                  POST   /posts/:post_id/votes(.:format)             votes#create
    new_post_vote GET    /posts/:post_id/votes/new(.:format)         votes#new
   edit_post_vote GET    /posts/:post_id/votes/:id/edit(.:format)    votes#edit
        post_vote GET    /posts/:post_id/votes/:id(.:format)         votes#show
                  PUT    /posts/:post_id/votes/:id(.:format)         votes#update
                  DELETE /posts/:post_id/votes/:id(.:format)         votes#destroy
            posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                  POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
         new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
        edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
             post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                  PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy


--WEBrick 

Started GET "/posts/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=Z8LuvU7i5ytFi1OxiIGpgwYOy%2BWE%2BfiAZv7m7T%2BwYRI%3D&post%5Bis_link%5D=true&post%5BURL%5D=http%3A%2F%2Ffirsttimers.co&post%5Bdescription%5D=My+first+time.&commit=save+post" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-20 22:37:52 -0400
Processing by PostsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Z8LuvU7i5ytFi1OxiIGpgwYOy+WE+fiAZv7m7T+wYRI=", "post"=>{"is_link"=>"true", "URL"=>"http://firsttimers.co", "description"=>"My first time."}, "commit"=>"save post"}
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 11.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Any help towards a solution and/or explanation as to what I am overlooking and whats going on (I hope it's not a typo... lol) will be greatly appreciated.

```
-- EDIT. HTML Generated code for posts/new.html.erb

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PostEmHigh</title>
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/posts.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/posts.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="Z8LuvU7i5ytFi1OxiIGpgwYOy+WE+fiAZv7m7T+wYRI=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

    <h5>Posts#new</h5>
<small><i>Find me in app/views/posts/new.html.erb</i></small>
<hr />

<div class="hero hero-unit">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/posts" class="new_post" id="new_post" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Z8LuvU7i5ytFi1OxiIGpgwYOy+WE+fiAZv7m7T+wYRI=" /></div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">
                <label for="post_Select post type">Select post type</label> 
            </label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="post_is_link" name="post[is_link]"><option value="true">Link</option>
<option value="false">Text</option></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="URL"><label for="post_URL">Url</label></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="post_URL" name="post[URL]" size="30" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="description"><label for="post_description">Description</label></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea cols="40" id="post_description" name="post[description]" rows="5">
</textarea>
            </div><br />
            <div class="controls">
                <input name="commit" type="submit" value="save post" />
</form>         </div>
        </div>
    </form> 
</div><!-- end hero, hero-unit CLASS -->

    <pre class='debug_dump'>--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: Z8LuvU7i5ytFi1OxiIGpgwYOy+WE+fiAZv7m7T+wYRI=
post: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
&nbsp; is_link: &#x27;true&#x27;
&nbsp; URL: http://firsttimers.co
&nbsp; description: My first time.
commit: save post
action: new
controller: posts
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just uninstalled and re-installed rails. This did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the url option in the form helper and try again

To be sure its not from you,

Run a scaffold generator for your post resource

```
rails g scaffold post is_link:boolean url description:text
```

you can use twitter bootstrap themed generator option to regenerate your bootstrap style if you want

Comment: Hello Uchenna, I have edited this code to reflect your instructions. I'm afraid that my submit button isn't hitting the create action yet.

Comment: did you upgrade your rails app to rails 3.2.8 of u just using old rails code(based on your index action)

Comment: It says another migration is already named create_posts. I'm not quite sure what just happened. Was I running rails g scaffold to ensure that I didn't have any typos or route inconsistencies? BTW thx for helping on a Sat night! Yeah, my gemfile says 3.2.8

Comment: you can delete the migration and run d generator again

Comment: the migration can be found in your RAILS_ROOT/db/migration folder

Comment: Ok I deleted the migration. I chose not to overwrite my view files when given the option and my issue persists. Should I have overwritten the views as well?

Comment: if you want but not actually necessary cos it generates the same thing

Comment: in the migration create table posts set the force to true to overwrite the exiting post table `create_table :posts, :force => true do |t|`

Comment: Ok I added the :force => true to my create_posts migration file. Do I need to run any further commands for that change to take effect? If not, then I receive the same error.

Comment: is the post being created or not

Comment: Thanks Uchenna, after uninstalling and re-installing ruby and rails, I ran another post scaffold as you suggested and although I don't see what I did (it appears identical to the previous code), the posts are now saving to the db as hoped.

Answer (score 0):

Could you copy the HTML code generated for your form? Also, try this:

```
form_for @post, :url => posts_path(), :method => :post
```

and copy the HTML code of your form.

Comment: Hello edelpero, I have added the HTML generated code. Its located at the end of my question. Also I have added the url hash and method with no success.